# Entity Framework with Ntier

Tags: c#, entity-framework, n-tier-architecture

I just start studying Entity  Framework, do i still have to create Business Logic and Poco models project on my Solution if i used EF as my DataAccess Class?

In my Apps Lately i used to create project into layers as DataAccess,BusinessLogic,PocoModel(entities) and Ui(windows app) using ADO.NET.

Do EF on vs 2008 as my dev tool is almost same as vs 2010?.

Thanks in Regards

Comment: If you have the option, use EF 4 (the one that shipped with Visual Studio 2010). It has a lot of improvements compared with the old version. You might also want to check this article out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee335715.aspx

Comment: I still need to use vs 2008.. :(

Comment: Are you using a SQL Database? Are you developing Code-First or Database-First? Are you manually creating your POCO classes and allowing Entity Framework to handle the data access?

Answer (score 0):

VS 2008 x VS 2010 makes a big difference because only VS 2010 supports Entity Framework 4 and only Entity Framework 4 has native support for POCOs. If you want to use Entity Framework 1 (.NET 3.5 SP1 + VS 2008) and POCOs you must use `EntityObjects` (heavy dependent on EF) and either convert them to POCOs manually or use [the adapter](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/EFPocoAdapter). `EntityObjects` in EFv1 must be defined in the same assembly as EDMX (entity model).

If you don't use POCOs you can place both data access and business logic into same assembly and reference it from UI. If you use POCOs you can stick with your architecture.